# LUA, Unpack all the hierarchy of a Nested Table and store and return Table with all the elements at the same hierarchy

Tags: lua, lua-table

I have a nested array, for example,

*someTable = {"value1", "value2", {"value3a", "value3b", {"value4a", "value4b", "value4c"}}*

and trying to find a way to get all of these different elements at different hierarchies to actually come down to a single hierarchy

expected results,

*newTable = {"value1", "value2", "value3a", "value3b", "value4a", "value4b", "value4c"}*

I've found this below code that actually prints all those elements, but I couldn't find a way to make it into a new table with one hierarchy an return it

```
function DeepPrint (e)
    -- if e is a table, we should iterate over its elements
    if type(e) == "table" then
        for k,v in pairs(e) do -- for every element in the table
            print(k)
            DeepPrint(v)       -- recursively repeat the same procedure
        end
    else -- if not, we can just print it
        print(e)
    end
end
```

Comment: The proper term for this is to `flatten` the table, with that information you can find a code like this [lua flatten table](https://gist.github.com/bofm/70766566ecd4edee76f8f17ffa7362c9)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with what Doj is saying, but you don't need two functions to do that.
Just recursively call initial function, like you did with your print example above.

```
#! /usr/bin/env lua
someTable = {"value1", "value2", {"value3a", "value3b", {"value4a", "value4b", "value4c"}}}

function flatten( item, result )
    local result = result or {}  --  create empty table, if none given during initialization
    if type( item ) == 'table' then
        for k, v in pairs( item ) do
            flatten( v, result )
        end
    else
        result[ #result +1 ] = item
    end
    return result
end

newTable = flatten( someTable )
for i = 1, #newTable do print( newTable[i] ) end
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of printing the elements just insert them to result table:

```lua
function flattenRecursive(e, result)
    -- if e is a table, we should iterate over its elements
    if type(e) == "table" then
        for k,v in pairs(e) do -- for every element in the table
            flattenRecursive(v, result) -- recursively repeat the same procedure
        end
    else -- if not, we can just put it to the result
        table.insert(result, e)
    end
end

function flatten (e)
    local result = {}
    flattenRecursive(e, result)
    return result
end
```

Test:

```lua
example = {"value1", "value2", {"value3a", "value3b", {"value4a", "value4b", "value4c"}}}
example_result = flatten(example)
for k,v in pairs(example_result) do
    print(v)
end
```